# Split list based on rows of list items

Tags: r, list, split

I'm trying to split my list of data frames into some kind of sub groups like a nested list or several lists. The split should be based on the number of rows per data frame, so data frames with the same number of rows should end up in the same list.

```r
full_list <- list(
  df1 = replicate(10, sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
  df2 = replicate(10, sample(0:1, 15, replace = TRUE)),
  df3 = replicate(10, sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE)),
  df4 = replicate(10, sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))
)
```

There are now two data frames with `nrow() == 10`, so they should end up in their own list or sublist

I tried something like this, but I don't think `split` is applicable for lists:

```r
sublist <- lapply(full_list, function(x) split(full_list, f = nrow(x)))
```

---

BTW: The greater goal is to split all data frames into a training and a test data set for machine learning with the function below. `sample` will be used to create the subsets, but I want the same `sample_vector` for data frames of same length. Therefore, I want to split the full list into sub lists beforehand. Afterwards I will put all data frames together again for further processing (kind of split - apply - combine). Just mentioning if I might be overcomplicating things here.

```r
# function to split data frames in each sub list into train and test data frames 
counter <- 0
train_test_list <- list()
for (x_table in sublist) {
  counter <- counter + 1
  current_name <- paste(names(sublist)[counter], sep = "_")

  sample_vector <- sample.int(n = nrow(x_table), 
    size = floor(0.8 * nrow(x_table)), replace = FALSE)
  train_set <- x_table[sample_vector, ]
  test_set  <- x_table[-sample_vector, ]

  train_test_list[[current_name]] <- list(
    train_set = train_set, test_set = test_set, 
    table_name = names(sublist)[counter]
  )
}
# combine all lists with test and train pairs back into one list 
full_train_test_list <- c(train_test_list1, train_test_list2, train_test_list3, ...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get the number of rows with `sapply` and `split` based on that info

```
new_list <- split(full_list, sapply(full_list, nrow))
str(new_list)
#List of 3
# $ 10:List of 2
#  ..$ df1: int [1:10, 1:10] 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 ...
#  ..$ df4: int [1:10, 1:10] 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
# $ 15:List of 1
#  ..$ df2: int [1:15, 1:10] 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
# $ 20:List of 1
#  ..$ df3: int [1:20, 1:10] 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 ...
```

As it is a nested `list`, we can do the processing in the inner `list` by calling `lapply` inside the first `lapply`

```
traintestlst <- lapply(new_list, function(sublst) lapply(sublst, function(x_table) {

     sample_vector <- sample.int(n = nrow(x_table), 
                size = floor(0.8 * nrow(x_table)), replace = FALSE)
      train_set <- x_table[sample_vector, ]
      test_set  <- x_table[-sample_vector, ]
      list(train_set = train_set, test_set = test_set)


     })
    )
```

-checking the output

```
traintestlst[[1]]$df1
#$train_set
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    1     0
#[2,]    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1     0
#[3,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1     0
#[4,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0     1
#[5,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1     0
#[6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0    1    0    1     0
#[7,]    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
#[8,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1     0

#$test_set
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0     1
#[2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     0
```

Comment: that looks great! Do you have a suggestion how to apply on each subset, e.g. how to adress them in a for loop? EDIT: I just saw `unlist` with `recursive = FALSE`, I will try that

Comment: @crazysantaclaus Now, we have a `list` of `list`.  You can use a nested `lapply` i.e. `lapply(new_list, function(sublist) lapply(sublist, yourfn))`

Comment: hey, thanks for your additional answer, that is perfect for me!

Comment: just one more thing, I'm trying to move the line generating the `sample_vector` up one level. ATM a new vector is created for each `x_table`, but it is supposed to change only for each `sublst`

Comment: @crazysantaclaus. You meant that the calculation for `sample_vector` would be from the first `lapply`, right.  In that case, just do `lapply(new_list, function(sublst) { sample_vector <- sample.int(n = nrow(sublist[[1]]), 
                size = floor(0.8 * nrow(sublist[[1]])), replace = FALSE); lapply(sublst, function(x_table) { use your sample_vector})})`

Comment: that is exactly what I just wanted to post, awesome!

Comment: We need to only subset the first `sublst` as th number of rows are the same for each of the sublst i.e. `sublst[[1]]`